# select the second element use css-selector in nightwatchjs

Tags: css-selectors, nightwatch.js

i have two elements have the same class name, how can i select the second element with the css-selcetor in nightwatchjs?

```js
client.assert.elementPresent('.ivu-menu-submenu-title')  // true
client.expect.element('.ivu-menu-submenu-title: last-child').to.be.visible // false
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHb28.png)

Answer (score 0):

To select a child element based on it's order you can do:

`element:nth-child(n) { }` this will select any element in the nth order regardless of it's parent

`parent child:nth-of-type(n) { }` this will select the nth child with respect to it's parent

n is the order of the element you want to style.
The parent can be element selector, class, id, attribute selector, etc.

You can test with those in addition with different selectors. This is the general idea how to do it.

You can do also do:

```
parent child:nth-of-type(n) .class-selector { }
```